# akka-http how to make browser generate authentication window?

Tags: scala, authentication, browser, akka, akka-http

I have Server.Route. I wanna get authentication window in browser, that asks user to type login and password.
I read in article that Server should return 401 error and authentication header to Client to make browser generate this window.

```
  val route =
  path("somepath") {
    get {
            respondWithHeaders(RawHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "somevalue"), Origin(HttpOrigin("http://akka.io"))) {
              complete(StatusCodes.Unathorized)
            }
           }
          }
```

I didn't get any authentication window in browser - only 401 error. 
If I'm doing something wrong? Do you know any other ways to get this window in browser?

Comment: Did you try `RawHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic")`?

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot! It works :)

Comment: Great to hear that :)